# How to get total redis cache size metrics in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have an application that runs in spring boot. Previously we have been using some java libraries for caching purposes. So we were able to get the cache_size from the spring boot metrics `actuator/prometheus`. Recently I have moved the caching to a centralized system such as Redis and the above metrics endpoint is no longer giving the total cache size in Redis. Is there a way we can get the total cache size in Redis using spring boot metrics ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the out of the box caching implementation / auto-configuration, adding the following lines in your properties file should work:

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.enable-statistics=true
```

If you have a custom implementation of [RedisCacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html), you should call the [enableStatistics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.html#enableStatistics--) on the builder when you create a new `CacheManager` `Bean`.